# I want to get an array which tells how many times an element is repeated?

Tags: javascript

The output is correct with bracket notation while output is something else with dot
notation

```
let data = ['car', 'car', 'truck', 'truck', 'bike', 'walk', 'car', 'van', 'bike', 
'walk', 'car', 'van', 'car', 'truck', 'Pogo '];

    let instance_1 = data.reduce((acc, elm) => {
       if(!acc[elm]){
         acc[elm] = 0;
        }
       acc[elm]++;
       return acc;
     }, {})
      console.log(instance_1)
    
    let instance_2 = data.reduce((acc, elm) => {
       if(!acc.elm) {
           acc.elm = 0;
          }
       acc.elm++;
       return acc;
     }, {})
     console.log(instance_2);
```

Your help is much appreciated...

Comment: `acc.elm` literally creates a property named `"elm"` so you have to use approach 1. Btw. you can simplify your reduce to `acc[elm] = (acc[elm] || 0) + 1; return acc;`

Comment: If the question is why `acc[elm]` works but `acc.elm` not, then the title is not correct -> [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask): _"Write a title that summarizes the specific problem"_

Comment: Question is not clear. You say you have the correct output, and alternative that does not give the correct output, and then "Your help is much appreciated". What is the question?

Answer (score 0):

when accessing `acc.elm` you're referring to an element called elm in the javascript object `acc`.

this is equivalent to accessing `acc["elm"]`.

So what you're doing in the second instance is accessing the same property for all elements.

for more info I'd suggest following [this page](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/dot-notation-vs-bracket-notation-in-javascript#:%7E:text=The%20dot%20notation%20is%20used,access%20object%20properties%20using%20variable.)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help, are you a web developer?

Answer (score 0):

In the first code, you are using `acc[elm]`, which is getting the element of `acc` whose key is the value of `elm`. That code works in the expected way and counts how many of each element there is in the array.

In the second code, you are accessing `acc.elm`, which is getting the property  named `elm` of `acc`. Since it always modifies the same property of `acc` (`acc.elm`), what your second `reduce` call will return is an object whose property named `elm` contains the number of elements in the array.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help, are you a web developer?

Answer (score 0):

In instance_2, you are creating a property "elm", by using dot notation. You use bracket notation when property identifiers have to be a String or a variable that references a String and dot notation when the property must be a valid JS identifier

For more details please read the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors)